# Can SharePoint 2010 Monitor Class Attendance and Activities?

Tags: excel, sharepoint-designer, office

The organisation I represent is a coaching company, with a number of coaches spread across the globe. One of the spreadsheets they use most frequently is a tracking sheet for all the people they coach. It contains

One of the spreadsheets commonly used in our organisation contains a list of class attendants on the left Y axis. On the top X axis is a list of tasks/objectives each attendant must achieve. It is the job of the coach first complete the list of attendants on the left Y axis, then mark of in the middle XY section of the sheet when each attendant has achieved each objective.

The list of tasks/objectives along the top X-axis can change, but only by senior staff within the organisation.

Is there any kind of SharePoint 2010 list this information can be put into? Please note the attendants will never likely see the system and therefore will never appear as users (this would be too difficult to manage as there are hundreds of them). My initial thoughts were to have at least three different lists (tasks, attendants, tasks completed), then create some sort of report which compiles the information in the lists together to produce what is currently seen on the spreadsheet. Can this information be captured using "out the box" SharePoint lists or "web parts" (?), or will I need to develop my own SharePoint components to capture and display this information?

Please bear in mind I've only been looking at SharePoint over the past 2 days :)

If any more info is required please let me know. Very much appreciate any guidance provided!

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be, but obviously the implementation is left out to you :)

You may want to look at these standard templates provided by Microsoft to achieve common tasks such as yours:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb407286

The above link is for 2007 version of sharepoint but you should be able to find these modified for 2010 version on google.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem I have right now is - which template to use? Looks like the only way to find out is through some experimentation...